# How to crop a character patch in a image in which the character lie vertical (not along diagonal)

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am a newbie at image processing, and I met a problem. I have searched for a long time on the net, but it was no use. Can you help me? Thanks very much.

Problem: crop a character patch in an image in which the character lies vertical. But usually in the result I get that character lies along diagonal. I do not know how to overcome it.

Here is an example. I want to get a patch that is marked by the green box, but I usually get the wrong result that is marked by red box.

My processing procedure:

- Read the image.
- Convert it to a single channel grey image.
- Find the contours.
- Filter the contours to get the character contours.
- Detect the minimum area rectangle according to the filtered contours.

Here is the code:

```
def processSingleImg(unresizedGrayImg):
    unresizedGrayImg = cv2.blur(unresizedGrayImg, (3, 3))
    unresizedGrayImg = equalizeHist(unresizedGrayImg)
    unresizedGrayImg = cv2.blur(unresizedGrayImg, (3, 3))
    edgeBinaryImg = cv2.Canny(unresizedGrayImg, 100, 220)
    _, contours, h = cv2.findContours(edgeBinaryImg, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    filteredContours = filterContourByAreaAndLength(contours)
    miniRotaRects = detecteMiniRotaRect(filteredContours)

    contoursImg = unresizedGrayImg.copy()
    contoursImg = drawCharacterContour(filteredContours, contoursImg)
    contoursImg = drawRotaRect(miniRotaRects, contoursImg)
    cv2.imshow("rotateRect", contoursImg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can you give me some tips? Thanks very much.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWamU.png)

Comment: Here the example image is : https://github.com/zongjuede/character-cropping-and-recognition/blob/master/mmexport1582567569127.jpg

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community, I made a few minor adjustments to the language and formatting of your question. If you can think of any other Tags you could add (for example, programming language in use) to your question, I'm sure that would also help finding an answer more quickly.

Comment: @Fabio Lolli Thanks for your kindness. Thank you.
The language is python.